# Bing AdCenter API java keyword report Campaignid

Tags: java, api, bing

I am working with the KeywordPerformance java report example. Is there a parameter for campaignid that will allow the request to pull all of the campaigns back for an account?

Comment: I would remove the Google AdWords tag. Your question is about the Bing's API.

Comment: Thanks!  Working on both at once :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set one or several client account ID/IDs. Set also the right scope.

```
    KeywordPerformanceReportRequest reportRequest = 
        new KeywordPerformanceReportRequest();

    // Specify the language of the report.
    reportRequest.setLanguage(ReportLanguage.English);

    // Specify the format of the report.
    reportRequest.setFormat(ReportFormat.Xml);
    reportRequest.setReturnOnlyCompleteData(false);
    reportRequest.setReportName("Keyword Report");
    reportRequest.setAggregation(ReportAggregation.Daily);

    reportRequest.setTime(.....);

    // Specify the scope of the report.
    AccountThroughAdGroupReportScope scope = 
        new AccountThroughAdGroupReportScope();
    scope.setAccountIds(ids);
    reportRequest.setScope(scope);
```

See also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bing-ads-reporting-keywordperformancereportrequest.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bing-ads-reporting-accountthroughadgroupreportscope.aspx

Then also call these if you like:
reportRequest.setFilter
reportRequest.setColumns

So I think the answer is:
Just don't set any CampaignIDs.
Provide only the client account(s) ID(s).